# Where does my data save from my MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am trying a crud operation in MVC from a website tutorial.  I write code for save and display data in my webpage.  I add connectionstring in my webconfig and follow the instruction as per tutorial. But now the problem is I does not find my data in my sql server database who's connectionstring I provide.

I don't know where it is saving my data I write this code for save and display data

for display data I write this in my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var books = from book in _db.Book
                        select book;
            return View(books.ToList());
        }
```

This is for insert data

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                Books book = new Books();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    book.Title = collection["Title"].ToString();
                    book.ISBN = collection["ISBN"].ToString();
                    book.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(collection["Price"]);
                    _db.Book.Add(book);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

And in my model I write this code for one class

```
public class BookDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Books> Book { get; set; }
    }
```

another class

```
public class Books
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String ISBN { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and I add connectionstring my webcofig.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ASPNETMVCApplication-20140628114535;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ASPNETMVCApplication-20140628114535.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
      <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTER18-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Intial Catalog=practice;UID=sa;pwd=***;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Where is my data saving?know.I need help about this topic I am not such aware about MVC.

Comment: show us the connectionstring?

Comment: check now @amarduplantier

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does the code inside the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block execute?

Comment: yes it is executed @AnthonyChu

Comment: Your datas is in App_Data directory in file aspnet-ASPNETMVCApplication-20140628114535.mdf

Comment: not it is empty @Pascalz

Comment: Its empty from Visual Studio because it's not part of project, look with explorer

Comment: yeah I looked there but there is nothing :( @Pascalz

Comment: hey @Pascalz I find it in my sql server not in my App_Data folder. But why it create a new database? I am working with a existing database

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using **VS12** or **VS13.**

Go to **View -> SQl Server Object Explorer.**

Look for server named **(LocalDb)\v11.0**

expand the database(name given by @Pascalz) in that server, you will find your data in one of the tables.

The template in visual stuio will create the database by default for saving account and membership information.

If you do not see (LocalDb)\v11.0, then try adding it by clicking Add Sql Server icon and connect using windows authentication

Comment: I get the solution. actually the connection string name in web config should be same as my model class. I did that and now it is working fine. But I still searching for it why it is necessary to add the connectionstring name same as model class? Do you know ? please tell me if you have any Idea

Comment: You can override that behavior by creating a constructor in your BooksDBContext that invokes the base constructor with whatever connectionstring or connectionstring name you want.